# PHP - Is concatenation possible between echo and print_r

Tags: php, concatenation, echo

In PHP, is it possible to write out an `array` within an `echo` command (or vice-versa)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, print_r() has an extra option to allow it to return the formatted text, instead of directly outputting it:

```
echo print_r($array, true);
```

Comment: Why not just `print_r($array)` ?

Comment: @xdazz because this is what the OP asked for

Comment: @xdazz: for this simple version, yeah. pointless. But the extra parameter would let you do `echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, true) . '</pre>';`

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you'd want to but you could possibly do

```
$var = print_r($array, true);

echo 'stack ' . $var;
```

to get the result your looking for

Comment: Not going to work. print_r() will perform output first, and return a boolean true, which is then concatenated with 'stack'.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot the flag on the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

`echo print_r($myVariable, true);`
The second param signals the function to return the output rather than a boolean of success.